# Trying to find out why a server is accessing struts.apache.org?

Tags: struts

I have a server on which there is evidence of accesses to http://struts.apache.org. Nobody has installed struts on it, but Tomcat 7.0 is certainly installed. Is is possible that Tomcat is performing those accesses? In case struts is included as part of Tomcat installation, how can I determine the struts' version. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule

That is an example of a TagLib (or TLD, tag library definition) from Tomcat 7.0. I would assume something during Tomcat's course of TagLib scanning it would accessing struts. Hard to tell based on the info provided.